# 1940s phototube collector material / datasheet for a tube

Tags: datasheet, materials, photosensor

I have browsed countless pages on Google but cannot find a datasheet that tells you the material/element of the collector plate (the semi-circular plate in the tube) in a phototube (not a photomultiplier).

The closest thing I have found is [this](http://www.ralphselectronics.com/productimages/RCA-935.PDF), for the [RCA 935 phototube](https://www.ebay.com/itm/274711207194?hash=item3ff6105d1a:g:4bgAAOSwAjlgRSjO&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsKXOOPhpjipe%2FZc5tkcsRRRtfR0uQ29yb8JX47%2BH%2FLr4PqNXAUtorJUyeWMO%2FyoqBDfu164288hyQ0Gi44f1iL2dx6RauKrkQ5k6TDD7aT8D9LDE2e4KsZrINT1SJEwo1rnDPtZnIFYmKs%2FBETN%2FaN9fqyOyvpt8aUDzB%2F7sG9kmqZO8B%2B7n85ixzPRi6b8apDYclRuOqyT2RfR1sqAYEGFobUVWzAmn16jrNj5eWl%2Bq%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR-75t7zaYA). How would I find the specifics of components like the RCA 935 phototube or of the [GE 1P40 phototube](https://www.ebay.com/itm/134189063842?hash=item1f3e4a9ea2:g:iHIAAOSwsvlh1Plq&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoJGnRKOMEHhuen20L60c4cSQr3uxEhcCI8RjEacqdhdJpX1xrWtdc4Jh4uSZjB8WeFPtzu7FVazbR46Ig%2Bi2UR3kFMW4z8zk8jv06vW9f%2FOW8goLRG1JLbH4c835jzFhJKXA2LsRivhNhap5UnFKGbJlnp6mJI7R7D5AOiehSS67zZ74eIR2UYhNyTNQzE0kXwPbszuKel7iEPwTmdm1zs0%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR_b65rzaYA)?

[image]

Comment: Probably because manufacturers did not have to provide data sheets back then.

Comment: Back in the day they used databooks which hold lists of components and their relevant specs. I doubt many were digitized and made available online.

Comment: GE 1P40 phototube seems infrared sensitive. Some I find http://www.decadecounter.com/vta/tubepage.php?item=26  1P41 http://www.decadecounter.com/vta/pdf/1p41.pdf

Comment: Some infos for "like" tubes http://www.decadecounter.com/vta/pdf/EmiPhotomultiplierTubesSupplement1972.pdf  http://www.decadecounter.com/vta/pdf/EmiPhotomultiplierTubes1970.pdf

Comment: Some info hamamatsu https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/etd/PMT_handbook_v3aE.pdf

Comment: Changed your title to not ask for the "helper" (namely, you're hoping to find datasheets containing manufacturing details, which most datasheet might conspiciously omit), but for  the actual knowledge (the material you're interested in).

Comment: Other question: why would that material be different to that of any other vacuum tube's plate? It's just collecting accelerated electrons, right? Do you have anything specific that raises this question? Adding your prior knowledge and considerations might greatly help lead the right experts to your question!

Comment: https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_1p40.html http://www.tubebooks.org/Books/Atwood/RCA%201940%20Vacuum%20Tube%20Design.pdf

Comment: @MarcusMüller Agree, the text is a misnomer; it does collect, but it's collecting light, and actually emitting electrons. Typically these tubes used just a piece of wire for the actual anode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The IP40 uses an **S-1** photo surface, which is composed of silver, oxygen, and cesium. It has a broad response over the entire visible range that peaks in the red and near-IR. You can take it that by saying **S-1**, it means that it was the first (hence the **1**) commercially successful photo surface.

The 935 on the other hand was a highly *non-standard* device, in that it's anode wire diameter was about half the usual, with a semi-cylindrical photo-cathode having a radius, compared to the anode radius, ratio that was unusually high. (Long topic there, including an odd hysteretic behavior.) The 935 uses an **S-5** photo surface (cesium and antimony) that featured an unusually low dark current and required a UV-transparent glass (fused silica or specialty quartz) envelope.

I've drawn out a simplified chart for the different surface types taken from an old RCA tube manual:

[image]

The bottom line is that there is a great deal of information available on these tubes. You just need to grab up an RCA tube manual somewhere. They go into a lot of useful detail. There are a number of versions dating back at least to 1940 (perhaps earlier) and continuing on well into the late 1960's, I believe. The earlier ones will cover only a few surface types. Later ones will cover far more. Look around.

Comment: Thanks so much, are you provide the name of the book that gave you the info?

Comment: @Darmstadtium It's gone by several names depending on the year and what was included in it. But generally called the "RCA Tube Manual," just as I mentioned in the text. Or something similar. If you google for s-1, s-2, etc., along with RCA and tube, I suspect you'll find a useful PDF somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Phototubes use the photoelectric effect, meaning, instead of a thermionic cathode emitting electrons by heat, a photoemissive layer emits electrons driven by absorbed light.  Which gives us some keywords to follow.

You may find this of interest: http://journal.library.iisc.ernet.in/index.php/iisc/article/viewFile/3727/3765 (Bhide and Ghosh, *Photoemissive Materials -- A Review*, Indian Institute of Science Journal (Oct. 1977))

Likely one of the systems listed was in use when the 935 and similar types were introduced.  You can probably match up the optical responses with the plots here:
https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/049/suppinfo/rca_hb3_pdg.pdf
(RCA HB3 Electron Tube Manual, Photosensitive-device Guide section)